# Accessing value attribute in Protovis lines

Tags: protovis

I'm using Protovis Arc layout and I'd like to color links between nodes accoriding to the 'value' property defined in dataset. How can I access it?

Dataset is defined like that:
Nodes:
...
{nodeName:"Books"}
...

Links:
...
{source:1, target:4, value:20}
...

arc.link.add(pv.Line).strokeStyle(function(d) d.value > 10 ? "#cc0000" : "#eeeeee"); - does not work

Answer (score 4):

The `d` property refers to the node. There's no `value` attribute defined on the *node* in this case; the link weights are defined on the *links*, which is why the property function isn't doing what you expect.

You can rewrite your property function to access the link (rather than node) data. The link data is associated with the link's parent panel, and is available as the second argument:

```
.strokeStyle(function(d, p) p.value > 10 ? "#c00" : "#eee")
```

There's more of an explanation in the [layout documentation](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/docs/layout.html). And see also the [`pv.Layout.Network`](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/jsdoc/symbols/pv.Layout.Network.html) API reference:

> The `link` mark is added to a child
>   panel, whose `data` property is
>   defined as layout's `links` property.
>   The link's `data` property is then a
>   two-element array of the source node
>   and target node. Thus, poperties such
>   as `strokeStyle` and `fillStyle` can
>   be overridden to compute properties
>   from either the node data (the first
>   argument) or the link data (the second
>   argument; the parent panel data)
>   dynamically.